# MediaWiki edit history in composite files

Tags: mediawiki, wiki, mediawiki-api, mediawiki-templates

I have several MediaWiki files, which include a list of templates inside them. If I edit one of these files I can see the edit history. But if I edit a Template file, it's is not shown in the composite file. I know logically, the history belongs to the Template file, not the main file. But is there a way I can see the edit history of a template be included in a composite file as well?

Answer (score 0):

Not in Mediawiki, but since each history is available as a RSS feed, you could combine them to get a single flow RSS which probably solve your needs. Big downside is that you have to create each combination manually. I used rssmix.com to generate this example out of an article's history and a template used on that page: http://www.rssmix.com/u/4247980/rss.xml